# UPNP and .NET CompactFramework

Tags: c#, upnp, coldfusion

Is there any upnp framework for CF .NET?
There is mono.upnp source but it needs porting for CF.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the source of andrea upnp is compilable for cf